# trying to use staggerTo with GSAP

Tags: jquery, css, animation, meteor, gsap

Trying to get my images to start from bottom: 0 and opacity 1 and stagger in using greensock animation. I am not sure what i am doing wrong as my code looks valide, maybe i have been staring at it for too long.

I assume the the find() is not working how i want it to as i am not seeing an object with all the img elements in it.

Here is what my console is outputting:

```
[prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[0], context: document]
```

Here is my Script:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var mainText = $('ul.images li').find('img');
    console.log(mainText);
    var tween = TweenMax.staggerTo(mainText, 0.75, {
        opacity: '0',
        bottom: '300px',
        left: '50%'
    }, 0.3);
});
```

Here is my html:

```
    <ul class="images">
        <li class="image brain"><img src="img/science/brain.svg" class="img brain" alt="cell-watermark-bg"></li>
        <li class="image mitochondria"><img src="img/science/mitochondria.svg" class="img mitochondria" alt="cell-watermark-bg"></li>
        <li class="image microscope"><img src="img/science/microscope.svg" class="img microscope" alt="cell-watermark-bg"></li>
        <li class="image scientist"><img src="img/science/scientist.svg" class="img scientist" alt="cell-watermark-bg"></li>
        <li class="image beaker"><img src="img/science/beaker.svg" class="img beaker" alt="cell-watermark-bg"></li>
        <li class="image beaker-2"><img src="img/science/beaker-2.svg" class="img beaker-2" alt="cell-watermark-bg"></li>
        <li class="image atom"><img src="img/science/atom.svg" class="img atom" alt="cell-watermark-bg"></li>
        <li class="image dropper"><img src="img/science/dropper.svg" class="img dropper" alt="cell-watermark-bg"></li>
        <li class="image dna"><img src="img/science/dna.svg" class="img dna" alt="cell-watermark-bg"></li>
    </ul>
```

Here is my css(scss):

```
    ul.images {
        position: relative;
        .image {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            .img {
                position: absolute;
                height: 50px;
                opacity: 1;
                -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
                -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
                -o-transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
                transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
                &.dna {
                    bottom: -40px;
                    left: -30%;
                }
                &.scientist {
                    bottom: 40px;
                    left: -40%;
                }
                &.atom {
                    bottom: -60px;
                    left: 60%;
                }
                &.cell {
                    bottom: -90px;
                    left: -96px;
                }
                &.brain {
                    bottom: -130px;
                    left: 250px;
                }
                &.dropper {
                    bottom: -120px;
                    left: -20%;
                }
                &.beaker {
                    bottom: -60px;
                    left: 15%;
                }
                &.beaker-2 {
                    bottom: -100px;
                    left: 100%;
                }
                &.mitochondria {
                    bottom: -40px;
                    left: 120%;
                }
                &.microscope {
                    bottom: 45px;
                    left: 110%;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in your scss. `ul.images{...}` wasn't actually being closed. I've closed it and the animation appears to work as I understand your question.

[Codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZvNOm?editors=0110)

Note: I've wrapped your js into a one second timeout so you can see elements placed onto the stage before the animation fires.

It's a bit odd that your sass compiler didn't shout at you saying there was something wrong.

Comment: thank you. I ended up figuring out it was never closed shortly after i posted although i did notice that i am unable to do callback functions. i pretty much copied working copies straight from GSAP docs and I still get a typeerror this.callback does not exist. I am stumped and beginning to think it is a Meteor issue not GSAP. Have you ran into a problem with using  gsap callbacks in Meteor?

Comment: Unfortunately I've never used Meteor as client requirements never need it. I should really start experimenting with it soon though :).

Comment: I just started using it a four months ago and loved it as soon as i started working with it. Definitely worth a look in my opinion.Again, thanks for the help!